# INSERT statement mystery - mysql_query returns true, yet no new rows appear in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I must be doing really stupid here. I've been troubleshooting this for 3 days with no luck.

Here is the PHP string that is sent to mysql_query():

```
insert into post_replies (postID, fromID, toID, status) values ($id, $userID, $toID, ".g_unread.")
```

Before you say, "Ah-hah, there must be an error in the SQL", please note these two things:

1. mysql_query() returns true (1)
2. I export the string to a text file (see below) BEFORE sending to mysql_query() - If I paste the exported text into the same mysql_query() statement, it works fine (new row appears) - If paste the exported text into phpMyAdmin, it works fine (new row appears)
3. The *exact* (and I mean *exact*, as in I simply copy and pasted it) same query is used a few lines down and it always works fine

Another thing I tried was to load the query *back* from the text and then send it to mysql_query() - but that produces the same odd behavior - it returns success (1), yet no new rows are actually inserted.

I have showed this to another programmer, who complained about my PHP coding style. He said INTs should be wrapped as strings and I should use curly braces around those (e.g. '{$id}'). However, of course that fixed nothing, the behavior was exactly the same. If there was a problem with string generation then the problem would appear in the query that is exported to text file before sending to mysql_query(). He also complained that I was using outdated mysql functions (that I should be using mysqli functions). However, that does not explain why my hundreds of other queries sent via mysql_query() work fine, including the one a few line below this one. It does not explain why the query works fine if I paste the exported-to-text-file text directly into mysql_query().

Thank you so much. I am totally lost here.

UPDATE #1: By request, here is the code around the statement:

```
$q = "insert into post_replies (postID, fromID, toID, status) values ($id, $userID, $toID, ".g_unread.")";
$result = mysql_query($q);
if ($result == true) {
    z($q);
} else {
    z('failure');
}
```

z() is a function I use for easily exporting to text file. Btw, the query is always sent to z(), 'failure' is never sent.

Here is an example of what is sent to the text file:

```
insert into post_replies (postID, fromID, toID, status) values (2039, 8, 1, 1)
```

Please keep mind that if I paste that text into phpMyAdmin, or into the mysql_query() function above, the row is inserted.

UPDATE #2: Due to concern by some, I have updated this part of the code to use mysql[i]

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(g_db_server, g_db_user, g_db_pass, g_db);
$result = $mysqli->query($q);
```

I now make a separate connection, just for this single query. However, the behavior is exactly the same. It returns true, but no news rows are created. However, if I export $q to a text file, and then paste that text into $mysqli->query() above, it works fine and the new row is created as expected.

Since everyone seems to have given up, I am now working on isolating the problem to single MySQL table / PHP file which anyone can download and try for themselves.

UPDATE #3: Solved! Sort of. It seems to be an issue with the surrounding code, causing the row to be deleted after insertion. However, this still doesn't explain why mysql_insert_id() returned 0. Perhaps mysql_insert_id() breaks on composite keys. Anyhow, I don't care - because it's fixed. I will give the check to @user1231958 because his answer was the closest. Thank you all immensely for your help and sorry for being tricked by mysql_insert_id()

Comment: Have you tried using the resulting query yourself? If so, what was the result?

Comment: need to start getting rid of `mysql_query` and use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) isntead

Comment: @user1231958 As stated above: "If I paste the exported text into the same mysql_query() statement, it works fine (new row appears) - If paste the exported text into phpMyAdmin, it works fine (new row appears)"

Comment: @user1301840 As stated above: "He also complained that I was using outdated mysql functions (that I should be using mysqli functions). However, that does not explain why my hundreds of other queries sent via mysql_query() work fine, including the one a few line below this one. It does not explain why the query works fine if I paste the exported-to-text-file text directly into mysql_query()."

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for not reading. If the same query, some lines later, works, then maybe the problem is not in the query but the context, can you post the code next to the query? Oh, you can also try committing the changes!

Comment: @user1231958 I just want to make a suggestion since they won't update `mysql_query` anymore, might as well migrate to prepare statement type. maybe those would help solving the problem.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Might be something missable like you assign the query to one variable, but execute a second variable by mistake?

Comment: @user1231958 I tried START TRANSACTION (before) and COMMIT after the statement, but nothing changed. Also, more surrounded code has been added.

Comment: @user1301840 I'm willing to try a different mysql function if it helps you troubleshoot, but I don't know how and I fear that might complicate things if I do it wrong

Comment: @Robbie More code is posted -- Thank you all

Comment: Hey, shouldn't g_unread have a $ before it?

Comment: Do you have a "test" database and a "real" database - you're posting to one, but checking the other? (Wouldn't explain why it would work if you copied the text directly into the query, but that makes no sense - there's something else going on!)

Comment: @Robbie There's only one DB - and as you pointed out, pasting the exported text info the same function works

Comment: I got the same issue here. Tried everything I found here, but no luck.

Comment: :), forgot to wrap delete under condition, just like you... thanks a ton for the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use grave accent's when specifying your tables and rows,

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `post_replies` (`postID`, `fromID`, `toID`, `status`) VALUES ('$id', '$userID', '$toID', '".g_unread."')";

$result = mysql_query($q);
    if ($result == true) {
        z($q);
    } else {
        z('failure');
    }
```

Tell me if if that works.

Comment: I tried adding grave accents, but nothing changed. It returned success, but no rows appeared in the table. As proof, here is the relevant line from the mysql log: `50 Query /* 1234 */ insert into `post_replies` (`postID`, `fromID`, `toID`, `status`) values (2051, 8, 1, 1)` It appears in the log - it returned success (1), but yet no new row. However, if I use the exported query (will a fully literal string, it works fine and the new row appears: `$q = "/* 1234 */ insert into `post_replies` (`postID`, `fromID`, `toID`, `status`) values ('2052', '8', '1', '1')";`

Comment: Although this was not the solution - I'm giving you the check because one of your comments was the closest to the solution. Thank you.

Comment: So what was the solution? For interests sake?

Comment: See UPDATE #3 in the original post for the solution. It was a logic error combined with an unrelated (still unsolved) confusing return value from mysql_insert_id()

Answer (score 0):

Does `mysql_error()` return anything? This maybe lame, but are you connecting to the right database while performing the insert?

You could also enable query logging in mysql to record all queries. Howtogeek has an [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/) on enabling this feature. After the server is restarted, you should start seeing all queries logged into the file you specified. Mine looks like this.

```
/opt/local/libexec/mysqld, Version: 5.1.61-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
120727  8:57:09     1 Connect   root@localhost on foo
            1 Query /* test comment */ insert into test(foo) values(NOW())
            1 Quit
```

Now that you can monitor all queries going to the mysql server, prefix your query with a comment to identify it in the log. I used the following PDO code to generate the log above.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foo",'root','');
$dbh->exec("/* test comment */ insert into test(foo) values(NOW())");
```

Comment: mysql_error() returns nothing. It's definitely connecting to the right database because, again, if I paste the exported text into the same function, it works fine. Besides, there is only one database. I added the log and added a comment to the query. Here is what turned up in the log: `20 Query /* 1234 */ insert into post_replies (postID, fromID, toID, status) values (2049, 8, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem just like this. I found the problem to be fields not having a default value.... I recently went from a Linux server to a Windows server and must have got a bit lazy while using Linux.

The problem was, when using my Linux server i don't have to put every single field into the INSERT query, for some reason (I'm not sure why) it seems to default them for me however, the Windows server I'm using does so the mysqli error function was saying no default for some fields, add these fields in and it worked fine for me.

I know this question has been answered but this might help other people having the same problem, after all i don't want someone else pulling their hair out for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if there is something prevent committing your command,
try this command after executing the query:
mysql_query ( "COMMIT;" );

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and found the problem.

If, somehow, your table doesn't have a correct auto-increment for a primary key it will return true but not actually insert the new row.